# Certain Website consuming LOT of RAM under Edge but lower RAM otherwise

Tags: windows-10, troubleshooting, microsoft-edge

I am running into a bizarre problem and I would like to know how can this happen and how to fix it if possible.

While accessing website like "wwww.icy-veins.com" which is a popular guide repository for all blizzard games. I have it open on my secondary monitor while having the actual game running on the main monitor. I don't know if the problem is unique to this website but it could very well be non-specific to that particular website.

So as a consequence if the website is hogging all of the RAM then the game stop working as well. For some weird reasons opening only two page is enough to burn 6000 MB via system manager through microsoft edge. But if I do the same with 6 pages from icy-veins plus other pages under chrome (have not tested firefox) it comes up to about 1500 MB split across multiple process which isn't as bad as microsoft edge.

Googling seem to come up with nothing that is useful except for articles from 6-7 years ago for older version of Internet Explorer from when it was still a thing.

Comment: open a cmd.exe (started as admin) and run this command: **wpr.exe -start EdgeBrowser  -start ReferenceSet -filemode && timeout -1 && wpr.exe -stop C:\EdgeBrowserUsage.etl** and capture the memory usage grow for 1-2 minutes, and press a key in the cmd to stop logging. Zip the ETL and share the ZIP via OneDrive. I'll take a look what Edge is doing.

Comment: I think I mess up something but it did capture some data. Just couldn't tell it to stop. It is rather huge file btw. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1j-VPbMVF-1TFlOYm5Ec0J5OGs

Comment: you captured some Chrome usage, but not from Edge. When you copy & pate the command and run it, it starts capturing. when you want to stop it, simply press a key inside the cmd. you can also run the commands separately: **wpr.exe -start EdgeBrowser -start ReferenceSet -filemode**, press ENTER now do the edge actions, go back to cmd and run **wpr.exe -stop C:\EdgeBrowserUsage.etl** and press ENTER again

Comment: Ok looks like it was running for 22 hours if I do a wpr.exe -status and if I try to type wpr.exe -stop C:\EdgeBrowserUsage.etl. It throw an error code 0xc55830000 and said there is "no process running" despite what status said. I tried googling the error code nothing shows up which is weird since there are usually document for things like this.

Comment: run the 2 commands on its own and capture the usage

Comment: Nevermind look like I manage to record and use wpr properly this time. It was a long time to upload at 1 GB! https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1j-VPbMVF-1ajNGX1UwQ0NmaTQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the trace with [WPA to analyze the Reference Sets data](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/wpa-reference-set#reference-set-outstanding-size-by-process) shows that most memory is done by Chakra.dll (JavaScript DLL of Edge) while parsing/executing JavsScript code.

```
Line #, Category Class, Impact Type, Process, Page Category, Impacting Stack, Impact Size (Process View) (MB), Size (Process View) (MB)
25, , , , ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- edgehtml.dll!CScriptCollection::ParseScriptText, 85,266, 85,266
26, , , , ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    edgehtml.dll!CJScript9Holder::ParseScriptText, 85,266, 85,266
27, , , , ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    Chakra.dll!ScriptEngine::ParseScriptText, 85,266, 85,266
28, , , , ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    Chakra.dll!ScriptEngine::ParseScriptTextCore, 85,266, 85,266
29, , , , ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- Chakra.dll!ScriptEngine::CreateScriptBody, 74,602, 74,602
30, , , , ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    Chakra.dll!ScriptEngine::DefaultCompile, 74,602, 74,602
31, , , , ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- Chakra.dll!ScriptEngine::CompileUTF8, 74,598, 74,598
32, , , , ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- Chakra.dll!ScriptEngine::CompileUTF8Core, 74,586, 74,586
33, , , , ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- Chakra.dll!GenerateByteCode, 67,293, 67,293
```

Try the an adblocker like [µblock origin](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/ublock-origin/9nblggh444l4) because I see several ads related js code gets loaded.

I have no other ideas how to fix this. While testingEdge I also saw several perf issues, so that I no longer use Edge at all.

Comment: Not too surprising that ads is burning memory. After all the page does seem to refresh ads from time to time.